# Align 'back' button with other button

Tags: swiftui

How can I align the 'Save' button with the back button. I want them on the same height. I can't seem to find anything about it online.

[image]

```
NavigationView {
    ZStack {
        setBackgroundColor.black
            .ignoresSafeArea(.all)
        
        ScrollView {
            VStack {
                HStack {
                    TextField(text: $workoutName) {
                        Text("Your Workout Name")
                            .foregroundColor(CustomColor.systemGray)
                    }
                    .textFieldStyle(RoundedTextFieldStyle())
                    .frame(width: 200)
                    
                    Spacer()
                }
                .padding()
            }
            
            VStack {
                ForEach(excercises) { excercise in
                    if self.selection.contains(excercise.id) {
                        AddWorkoutRow(title: excercise.name)
                    }
                }
            }
            
            VStack {
                Spacer()
                
                HStack {
                    Button(action: {
                        self.showSheet = true
                    }) {
                        Text("Add Exercise")
                            .frame(width: 200, height: 10)
                            .foregroundColor(CustomColor.darkBlue)
                            .padding()
                            .background(CustomColor.cyan)
                    }
                    .clipShape(Capsule())
                    .sheet(isPresented: $showSheet) {
                        AddWorkoutSheet(selection: $selection)
                    }
                }
                .padding()
            }
            
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                    Button(action: {
                        print("Test this button.")
                        
                    }) {
                        Text("Save")
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("Create a Template")
        }
    }
}
```

I tried different positions for the 'Save' button, but it does not change to the same height. The navigationTitle should remain as is, only the save button should be on the same height as the back button. There do not seem to be any placements for the toolbar item that achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably using one NavigationView in another NavigationView what causes your problem. Here is an example:

```
import SwiftUI

struct Exercise {
    var id: Int
    var name: String
    
    init(id: Int, name: String) {
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
    }
}

struct ChildView: View {
    @State private var showSheet: Bool = false
    @State private var selection: [Int] = []
    
    let exercices: [Exercise] = [Exercise(id: 1, name: "E1"), Exercise(id: 2, name: "E2")]
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ZStack {
                Color.white
                    .ignoresSafeArea(.all)
                
                ScrollView {
                    VStack {
                        HStack {
                            TextField(text: .constant("")) {
                                Text("Your Workout Name")
                                    .foregroundColor(.gray)
                            }
                            .textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
                            .frame(width: 200)
                            
                            Spacer()
                        }
                        .padding()
                    }
                    
                    VStack {
                        ForEach(exercices, id: \.id) { excercise in
                            if self.selection.contains(excercise.id) {
                                Text(excercise.name)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    
                    VStack {
                        Spacer()
                        
                        HStack {
                            Button(action: {
                                self.showSheet = true
                            }) {
                                Text("Add Exercise")
                                    .frame(width: 200, height: 10)
                                    .foregroundColor(.black)
                                    .padding()
                                    .background(.cyan)
                            }
                            .clipShape(Capsule())
                            .sheet(isPresented: $showSheet) {
                                // AddWorkoutSheet(selection: $selection)
                            }
                        }
                        .padding()
                    }
                    .toolbar {
                        ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                            Button(action: {
                                print("Test this button.")
                                
                            }) {
                                Text("Save")
                                    .foregroundColor(.black)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    .navigationTitle("Create a Template")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            NavigationLink(destination: ChildView()) {
                Text("Child View")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

If I am correct, the nested NavigationView must be removed. Here is an updated code without nested NavigationView:

```
import SwiftUI

struct Exercise {
    var id: Int
    var name: String
    
    init(id: Int, name: String) {
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
    }
}

struct ChildView: View {
    @State private var showSheet: Bool = false
    @State private var selection: [Int] = []
    
    let exercices: [Exercise] = [Exercise(id: 1, name: "E1"), Exercise(id: 2, name: "E2")]
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.white
                .ignoresSafeArea(.all)
            
            ScrollView {
                VStack {
                    HStack {
                        TextField(text: .constant("")) {
                            Text("Your Workout Name")
                                .foregroundColor(.gray)
                        }
                        .textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
                        .frame(width: 200)
                        
                        Spacer()
                    }
                    .padding()
                }
                
                VStack {
                    ForEach(exercices, id: \.id) { excercise in
                        if self.selection.contains(excercise.id) {
                            Text(excercise.name)
                        }
                    }
                }
                
                VStack {
                    Spacer()
                    
                    HStack {
                        Button(action: {
                            self.showSheet = true
                        }) {
                            Text("Add Exercise")
                                .frame(width: 200, height: 10)
                                .foregroundColor(.black)
                                .padding()
                                .background(.cyan)
                        }
                        .clipShape(Capsule())
                        .sheet(isPresented: $showSheet) {
                            // AddWorkoutSheet(selection: $selection)
                        }
                    }
                    .padding()
                }
                .toolbar {
                    ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                        Button(action: {
                            print("Test this button.")
                            
                        }) {
                            Text("Save")
                                .foregroundColor(.black)
                        }
                    }
                }
                .navigationTitle("Create a Template")
            }
        }
    }
}


struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            NavigationLink(destination: ChildView()) {
                Text("Child View")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

It is possible that I am wrong, but based on your question is not clear where the problem could be. Maybe you should provide us more informations.